# Capturing form submit events using enter in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My backbone.js form has a single textfield (no submit button). I need to capture submit event (using enter key) in the view. Below is the sample code. Somehow the submit method is not called on pressing enter. Instead the form goes for a reload.

Script :

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#form',

    events: {
        "submit": "submit",
    },

    initialize: function () {
        console.log("initialize");
    },

    submit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("submit");
    }
});

new FormView();
```

HTML :

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text"/>        
</form>
```

Answer (score 21):

Add this to your Backbone view:

```
events: {
  'submit form': 'submit'
}
```

Also, note that in your HTML, the form action has to be defined.

If you don't have the action defined, then do this:

```
events: {
  'keyup': 'processKey'
}

processKey: function(e) { 
  if(e.which === 13) // enter key
    this.submit();
}
```

Comment: it's actually 'keyup' - no CamelCase :)

Comment: You are missing a '{' for the if block

Answer (score 3):

If you're having trouble capturing submit events ensure that your 'el' property is defined in your view.

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(body), 
    events: {
       "submit form": "doMethod" 
    }, 
    doMethod: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        console.log('form fired');
    }  
});
```